# flutter How to create a folder-shaped container

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Hi,

I want to create a folder-shaped container like the image above.

I'm using customPaint to make it like the code below, but it doesn't work like the image above.

```
  Container(
                        width: 274,
                        height: 188,
                        child: CustomPaint(
                          painter: FolderShapePainter(color: Colors.blue),
                        ),
                      )

class FolderShapePainter extends CustomPainter {
final Color color;

FolderShapePainter({required this.color});

@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
Paint paint = Paint()
  ..color = color
  ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

Path path = Path();
path.moveTo(size.width, size.height * 0.3);
path.lineTo(size.width * 0.7, size.height * 0.3);
path.lineTo(size.width * 0.6, 0);
path.lineTo(0, size.height * 0.2);
path.lineTo(0, size.height);
path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
path.close();

canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}

@override
bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
return false;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you want CustomClipper or CustomPainter. If the folder is only going to be background and there is not going to be any child, you should chose CustomPainer but if it is going to have child, use CustomClipper instead as it will Clip the Folder structure.

I have added example of both CustomClipper and CustomPainer so that you could see the difference

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const lorem =
    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas porta ornare ex, non hendrerit libero pretium sit amet. Cras porta, nisi sed viverra elementum, enim massa ullamcorper nisi, vel consectetur ante justo id elit. Maecenas aliquet leo sit amet risus fringilla, sed blandit elit pretium. Integer ornare rutrum aliquam. Cras consequat justo nec eros semper elementum. Vestibulum in elit ipsum. Proin in nunc condimentum, ultrices neque a, scelerisque augue. Aliquam erat volutpat. Cras dui lectus, vestibulum at eleifend ut, scelerisque in libero.';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const title = 'Long List';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(title),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 274,
              height: 188,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: ClipPath(
                clipper: FolderShapeClipper(),
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 20,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: const Text(lorem),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 274,
              height: 188,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: CustomPaint(
                painter: FolderShapePainter(color: Colors.blue),
                child: const Text(lorem),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FolderShapeClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  final a = 0.10;
  final b = 0.25;
  final c = 0.5;
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(size.width * a, 0)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height * b)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height * b)
      ..lineTo(size.width * c, size.height * b)
      ..lineTo(size.width * c, 0)
      ..lineTo(size.width * a, 0)
      ..close();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}

class FolderShapePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Color color;

  FolderShapePainter({required this.color});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = color
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    const a = 0.10;
    const b = 0.25;
    const c = 0.5;

    Path path = Path()
      ..moveTo(size.width * a, 0)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height * b)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height * b)
      ..lineTo(size.width * c, size.height * b)
      ..lineTo(size.width * c, 0)
      ..lineTo(size.width * a, 0)
      ..close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: "I am not sure whether you want CustomClipper or CustomPainter" he wants a custom shape, so he needs a custom `ShapeBorder` that can be used directly in `Material`, `Card` or `Container` widgets - the same way `CircleBorder` or `RoundedRectangleBorder` or `StadiumBorder` are implemented in flutter

Comment: Thanks @pskink. ShapeBorder looks pretty good alternative. I have not create one myself yet. I tried helping here with whatever little knowledge I have gained. I will try to implement this with custom border.

Comment: Is it possible to give a shadow effect as in the image?

I wrapped it in a container and added a box shadow, but I see an ugly shadow effect that is completely different from the image.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76126754/i-am-using-flutter-the-shadow-effect-is-so-ugly

As a new question in the link, can you please check the shadow effect image and question I made and help you?